# Can we use the sawstop concept for metallic doors as well for home? If not how can we protect from door finger injuries?

Tags: embedded, physics, mechanical

Is it possible to apply the Sawstop concept where the system induces small current and monitors changes when human finger is inserted? If not what are the nest ways [for metallic doors that closes automatically like elevator]

Answer (score 1):

Elevator doors already have safety devices that prevent them from injuring or decapitating people.

[Here](https://www.si-instruments.com.au/download-centre/drivetest-fm300-pinch-elevator-door-tester-brochure/download.html), for example, is a test device for verifying "peak force, residual pinch force, energy, and velocity".

Now, if we think about the pinch hazard between a door near the door hinge and the frame on a heavy self-closing door, those things always give me the heebie-jeebies when I see delicate little child fingers near them. I'm not sure how you'd protect them- they're usually both aluminum or stainless steel so there's not much to detect but the resulting screams.

Comment: You'd almost be better just covering over the hinge with a flexible piece of plastic.

Answer (score 0):

The SawStop works safely as long as the saw blade and the arbor that it runs on drop down into the body of the saw cabinet when nobody else has body parts sticking in there.

The problem with trying to apply the SawStop concept to a door is that doors swing through to wide open space and if a door were to suddenly swing open very rapidly it would cause quite some damage to persons or property sitting in the way.